# Ajustar css tabla html

Tags: html, css, html-tabla

Estoy trabajando en una tabla desde HTML y CSS, lo que necesitaba era que el header quedara fijo el cual ya está pero el body no logro ajustarlo al tamaño del header de la tabla.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```css
load/* main elements */

tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { */
/*       background-color: blue; */
/* } */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
}

/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  */
/*        background-color: navy;  */
/*  }  */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 200px;
} 

table th {
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background: #0093e2;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 100px;
 padding: 6px;

}

}


.header_fijo {


}


.header_fijo table tbody {
 display: block;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="header_fijo ">
  <table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Correcto lo que dice Joel, recuerda que el CSS trabajar en tipo cascada, por lo que debes recorrer la ruta hasta el elemento de esta manera, quedando el código como te comentó Joel

Comment: Hola, acabo de seguir la sugerencia de Joel y el body no se ajusta al tamaño del header..tienes alguna otra sugerencia??

Comment: He visto bien tu código y le he realizado los ajustes necesarios, ahí te coloqué la solución Paula ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He estado buscando información acerca de como lograrlo sin js, pero solo he visto un demo que realiza lo que necesitas y es aquí: https://escss.blogspot.com.co/2014/10/responsive-table-encabezado-fijo-scroll.html y es un quizá un tanto más complejo de lo que supondrías.

Lo cierto es que **al convertir en elemento bloque al tbody, pierde la conexión que tenía con los tamaños de celda definidos en el thead** y por eso es que no conservan la relación de tamaño, deberias restaurarla manualmente.

Por tanto para conservar el header fijo, la solución más rápida que se me ocurre es que tienes que volver al thead en elemento block también.

```
.header_fijo thead{ display: block;}
```

A todos los elementos de la tabla le aplicaría un modelo de caja css3 y un layout fijo:

```
.header_fijo *{box-sizing: border-box; table-layout: fixed;}
```

Y te tocaria darle el mismo tamaño a las celdas, así:

```
.header_fijo tr>*{ width: 100px }
```

Por último corregir en la ultima celda de la fila del encabezado el ancho del scroll que definiste antes así:

```
.header_fijo thead th:last-child{ width: 110px }
```

Es 110px, porque es el suma del tamaño de las celdas + los 10px que le diste de ancho al scroll. Aquí un ejemplo:

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { */
/*       background-color: blue; */
/* } */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
}

/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  */
/*        background-color: navy;  */
/*  }  */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 200px;
} 

table th {
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background: #0093e2;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 100px;
 padding: 6px;
}

/*Desde aquí agregue los estilos*/

.header_fijo *{
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.header_fijo thead, 
.header_fijo tbody{
  display: block;
}

.header_fijo tbody {
 overflow: auto;
 height: 100px;
}

.header_fijo tr>*{
 width: 100px;
}

/*corregir el espacio del scroll a la izquierda del tbody*/
.header_fijo thead th:last-child{
  width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_fijo ">
  <table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
```

O definir una medida para cada columna así:

```
.header_fijo tr>*:nth-child(1){ width: 120px } /*la medida que gustes*/
.header_fijo tr>*:nth-child(2){ width: 100px } /*la medida que gustes*/
.header_fijo tr>*:nth-child(3){ width: 90px } /*la medida que gustes*/
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { */
/*       background-color: blue; */
/* } */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
}

/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  */
/*        background-color: navy;  */
/*  }  */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 200px;
} 

table th {
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background: #0093e2;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 100px;
 padding: 6px;
}

/*Desde aquí agregue los estilos*/

.header_fijo *{
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.header_fijo thead, 
.header_fijo tbody{
  display: block;
}

.header_fijo tbody {
 overflow: auto;
 height: 100px;
}

.header_fijo tr>*:nth-child(1){
 width: 120px;
}
.header_fijo tr>*:nth-child(2){
 width: 100px;
}
.header_fijo tr>*:nth-child(3){
 width: 90px;
}

/*corregir el espacio del scroll a la izquierda del tbody*/
.header_fijo thead th:last-child{
  width: calc(90px + 10px); /*estoy sumando el ancho del scroll*/
}
```

```html
<div class="header_fijo ">
  <table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, eso era justo lo que necesitaba, lo probé y funcionó correctamente.

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos :)

Answer (score 0):

En la línea del `CSS`

```
.header_fijo tbody { 
  display: block;// Eliminar
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Buscara el hijo `tbody` correctamente, pero este tiene una propiedad `display: block;` que no es necesario y es lo que origina este resultado. debería eliminar esta propiedad ya que desea solo  desea mostrar las filas y no se aplicó ningún estilo al `thead` . recuerde que el valor por defecto de la propiedad display para el `thead` es `display : table-header-group;` y para `tbody` `display :table-row-group;`

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { */
/*       background-color: blue; */
/* } */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
}

/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  */
/*        background-color: navy;  */
/*  }  */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 200px;
} 

table th {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #0093e2;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 100px;
  padding: 6px;

}

.header_fijo {


}

.header_fijo  tbody {
 overflow: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_fijo ">
  <table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
```

Aunque para que cumpla con el `tbody`  el estilo `height: 100px;` y `overflow: auto;` debería aplicar el `display:block` a ambos , tanto para `thead` como `tbody`

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { */
/*       background-color: blue; */
/* } */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
}

/* ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  */
/*        background-color: navy;  */
/*  }  */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 200px;
} 

table th {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #0093e2;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 100px;
  padding: 6px;

}

.header_fijo thead{
  display: block;
}

.header_fijo  tbody {
 display: block;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_fijo ">
  <table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
    <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola Joel gracias por la respuesta, acabo de modificarlo asi como me dices y el body sigue igual, debo agregarle alguna otra línea para que se ajuste al tamaño del header??

Comment: @PaulaMarín reproduciendo su fallo cambié mi respuesta , actualicé mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Sin embargo con sólo hacer lo que dijo Joel no funciona, aquí he chequeado el código y te he realizado la solución, pruebala y si te funciona calificas ;)

```css
    load/* main elements */

    tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #EFEFEF;
    }

    /* ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { */
    /*       background-color: blue; */
    /* } */

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
          width: 10px;
          height: 10px;
    }

    /* ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  */
    /*        background-color: navy;  */
    /*  }  */

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-radius: 200px;
    } 

    table th {
     font-size: 1.1em;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     background: #0093e2;
     border-radius: 6px;
     border: 100px;
     padding: 6px;

    }

    }


    .header_fijo {
width: 100%;

    }


    .header_fijo .tabla_resultados {
     display: block;
     overflow: auto;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header_fijo ">
  <table class="tabla_resultados">
 <thead>
  <tr>
 <th>Month</th>
 <th>Savings</th>
<th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
 <td>January</td>
 <td>$100</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
 <td>February</td>
 <td>$80</td>
<td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
  </div>



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

La probé en el compilador de SO y funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentarlo con este método del mismo blog que enlaza Edgar pero bastante más "actual" y simple tanto en la forma de lograrlo como en el comportamiento de la tabla:
https://escss.blogspot.com.es/2014/10/responsive-table-encabezado-fijo-scroll.html

Un saludo